# control Arduino board using Android sensors and wifi?

Tags: sensors, wifi, android

i am thinking about building a Quadcopter that can be controlled with a computer via Wifi . but the problem is that with a lack of components and limited resources , i have been thinking of using my available components ( Arduino uno + smart phone + quadcopter frame with 4 brush-less motors and 4 speed control ) 
so i am asking you guys if it is possible to read smartphone sensor values using Arduino usb and control the quadcopter using smartphone wifi ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible?  Yes, it's certainly possible.  You can read the sensor values from within an Android program. It's possible to get Android to communicate with the Arduino through the USB.  The Arduino can be programmed to respond to what it gets through the serial.

Is it easy? Well, that depends on how good you are at Android programming.

One good place to start might be the [ArduinoFirmata-Android](http://shokai.github.io/ArduinoFirmata-Android/) project.  Don't worry about programming the Arduino, just install Firmata on it.  Then it's all down to how you program the Android device.  The Arduino just becomes a peripheral to your phone.

Comment: it looks a little bit complicated , in addition i dont have so much knowledge about android programming !!! is there any other more simpler method ?

Comment: Yes there is. It's called "buying the right components".

Comment: Thank you for your help @Majenko . I think i have to start learning android  programming .